# How to display Powerpoint presentation on help button in Visual C# 2008 Express addition

Tags: c#

I want to display a powerpoint presentation on help button in my windows application which I have created in Visual C# 2008 express addition.

I have used the below code on help button to display PPT :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("",
            Process process = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            startInfo.FileName =System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\User Guide - MIB FIT IP Generator v1.0.pdf");
            MessageBox.Show(startInfo.FileName);
            //= Server.MapPath(@"\User Guide - MIB FIT IP Generator v1.0.pdf");
            process.Start();

        }
```

This works well and display the PPT. But When I make the setup of this windows application and run it on some different PC or computer then it does not run because it did not get the path of the PPT.

Can you guy help me with this issue. I want to display the PPT on click of help button and when I make the exe file or setup file of that project and run on different computers or PC. It should run on their machine as well.